# How can dynamic voltage and frequency scaling be controlled from software?

Tags: assembly, frequency

I know there are a lot of questions on how to do frequency or voltage scaling from a particular operating system, but I'm not interested in that. I'm from compilers background and would like to know how a compiler could perform frequency scaling if it has information on the application being compiled.

Specifically, I would like to know whether a specific assembly instruction is used to modify the frequency or voltage used by a cpu or is it something different.

Comment: No, there's isn't a specific assembly instruction. Typically dynamic changes like these are managed by hardware in the CPU itself and/or the chipset.

Comment: Maybe [this link to the Intel AMT tech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology) will give you some hints.

Comment: `wrmsr` in some sense. But the details are model specific, and you can't use it from user mode.

Comment: @zx485 I am talking about trying to modify the frequency of the processor from software in order to save power. I wanted to know if there was a way to do this from software, even at the assembly level.

Comment: @harold `wrmsr` is an instruction to write to a special register, usually used for debugging purposes. I wanted to know if it is possible for a compiler to control the cpu frequency or voltage

Comment: Some of those MSRs are performance settings. Also using `pause` may make the processor drop into a slower state, then again it may also not do that, it depends.

Comment: Operating systems can enter sleep modes to save power, but there's no specific instruction for doing so. How exactly its accomplished varies from motherboard to motherboard and in a typical system the CPU is only one of many devices that can be put in some sort of sleep mode. Operating system generally don't have any direct control over the CPU frequency. The CPU dynamically raises and lowers the frequency depending on whether the CPU appears to be idle or not and how hot the CPU is. OS control is limited to enabling or partially disabling the feature and being idle or not idle.

Comment: On x86 CPUs executing a PAUSE instruction in a loop, or a HLT instruction alone would acts an idle hint to the CPU, the later being a very strong hint but only available in ring 0.

Comment: @anirudh: This is certainly possible many systems though the details wary depending on the specific platform. For instance it is conventional for microcontrollers to offer a plethora of CPU clock options, with different source oscillators and divider settings, to reduce power use. Including gating the clock altogether until a wake-up event. Many MCUs also feature built-in programmable core voltage regulators. Typically this is all handled through a combination of I/O register, memory mapped or in a dedicated space, along with special instructions to enter sleep modes.

Comment: @anirudh - you should at least take a shot at specifying what hardware you are interested in. Since you are asking for assembly-level directives to control platform behavior, the answer will inherently be platform specific.

Comment: @BeeOnRope x86 should be fine. I just wanted to know whether control like that can be done. my interest is in getting the compiler to generate appropriate code with something like a flag while compiling.

Comment: I answer for x86 below. The answer is pretty definitely "no" for a compiler generating user code. At most you can give very vague hints, such as the use of `pause` for spinloops, but that's about it. Even the exact behavior of such hints is subject to [fairly radical change](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#477) from generation to generation.

Comment: On x86 all you can do is insert a PAUSE instruction to try to save power in things like spin locks where one thread is waiting on a thread running on a different CPU. Maybe call some OS specific service to request that the computer enter a "high-performance" or "power saving" mode, but it's not the sort of thing you'd expect a compiler into insert into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voltage and frequency scaling is typically controlled by a combination of hardware and software.

Beyond that it isn't possible to given a totally generic answer since the details are hardware-specific, so most of the below applies to Intel x86 hardware. Other "big" CPUs are likely similar, but something like a microcontroller is going to be quite different.

So the "software" part of the above might give you some hope that you can control it from your application, but the software side of things is generally restricted to the kernel, or in some cases processes running as root. In particular, most of the frequency control on recent Intel can be adjusted using MSR registers, and you could access this from userland using the [`msr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/msr.4.html) kernel module and the `rdmsr` and `wrmsr` commands.

This isn't a recommended way of doing things, because you are changing MSRs that the kernel is also setting, so things may go haywire, your changes may be arbitrarily undone, etc.

The recent trend in x86 is to push more of the "frequency control" loop into hardware, which can respond more quickly and has access to fine-grained metrics about application behavior that the application doesn't. On Intel this is the so-called HWP (hardware p-states) and is embodied in the `intel_pstate` drive for Linux (the default on recent Intel) and similar stuff on Windows. Here, software is relegated to giving more general hints to hardware, but generally doesn't control the frequency directly.

Finally, about voltage specifically: this usually isn't even directly controllable in a general way on x86 - you set what you can via the MSRs, and the voltage is set by the hardware to an appropriate level. Certain motherboards or "enthusiast" CPUs may offer drivers that can set the voltage directly at runtime, but these are far from universal.